# Caching in PHP(MySQL MEMORY engine)

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I would like to ask people who have experience with MySQL MEMORY engine. Is it a good choice for cheap and fast caching system.

Comment: What do you want to cache, how structured is it, what size are the objects, how many of them are you planning to use at once? (etc.) There's no "one-size-fits-all" answer, *much* more detail is needed. (Also, MySQL storage engines don't have anything to do with PHP.)

Comment: Yes, I understand, however I use PHP as my server side parser. My details are simple - as I perform SQL queries, a lot of them are the same for all the request and I would like to cache the results for some time. I would like to know if using MEMORY engine would be a good choice over simple text files or some caching engine like memcache, apc and etc.

Comment: FYI, if your queries are the same, MySQL already caches them for you, automagically: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html (this functionality is compiled in by default, but has to be enabled in MySQL config, see e.g. this: http://www.docplanet.org/mysql/mysql-query-cache-in-depth/ )

Comment: Maybe I've asked too quickly. Somehow I turned a good idea into a low quality question.

Comment: MySQL already has caching mechanisms in place for caching the same result set. You can leverage that by using Memcached (if the data is small enough) and cache it directly to RAM without the need to contact the db at all. Using Memory engine might add overhead to the whole deal because you'll have to copy the data to Memory engine. Also, there's the question of determining when to invalidate the cache and so on. Overall, take a look what MySQL can do already before going deeper with this.

Comment: Thank you N.B, Piskvor. Your answers definetely highlighted the right way for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheap and fast? Sure - it does the trick. And it's just so simple to write an SQL query instead of dealing with PHP extensions that you are unfamiliar with.

Basically, what I use it for is storing session data, but unless you want to populate it with huge amounts of content - I guess it's good for caching too.